# I dont understand why i get this error in my code. ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (24,) (26,)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I keep getting this error im not entirely sure what it means. i just started coding about 2 weeks ago. All i want to do is change my velocity graph into an acceleration graph.

i've tried changing the times function from times[1:] to times[2:]. i still get the same error message.

```
print(x)

print(y)

plt.scatter(times, y/np.max(np.abs(y)))

changex = np.diff(x) #takes difference in x plot points

changey = np.diff(y) #takes difference in y plot points

dt = np.diff(times)

plt.plot(times[1:],(changey/dt)/np.max(changey/dt))

plt.show()

velocity = (changey/dt)/np.max(changey/dt)

print(velocity)

changev = np.diff(velocity)

plt.plot(times[1:],(changev/dt)/np.max(changev/dt))

plt.show()
```

The line I believe to be giving me this issue is:

`plt.plot(times[1:],(changev/dt)/np.max(changev/dt))`

Comment: Having trouble with plt.plot(times[1:],(changev/dt)/np.max(changev/dt))
that line of code.

Comment: Have you tried calculating `(changev/dt)/np.max(changev/dt)` outside of the plotting call (or just `changev/dt`) to see if the calculation is the problem?? What are the shapes of `changev` and `dt`?

Comment: when  i do that outside the plot it says it doesn't fit 25 but it fits 24.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I'm a little unclear on what you mean. Do you get a broadcasting shape error?

Comment: yea i get the broadcasting error but only for 25 not 24

Comment: Then the issue seems to be that your arrays are of different sizes, likely due to `np.diff()` reducing the length of the array by 1. Have you checked your outputs after each `diff()` to make sure they are what you expect?

Comment: thank you for the help! i changed the plot statement to plt.plot(np.asarray(times)[2:],changev)